# how to read URL behind element / object?

Tags: javascript, html, object, stream, tampermonkey

I wonder if there is any .js / app to do this:

there is a hosting site site.aa which hosts many diferent URL's and one of those URL is site.bb/x and I would need to pin point that URL via URL mask (which I would set up in some settings) and copy it (into clipboard)

I'm just trying to avoid this procedure:
while on a site site.aa press ctrl+shift+i (chrome) >> locate site.bb/x in source code >> copy URL (>> open desktop player >> insert URL)

---

edit:

well its html5 video (mp4) and the idea is to send it into deafult desktop player which supports URL inputs. but I guess I would by fully satisfied if it would be some .js script which would be placed in right context menu (of the mouse) and also it would have some options or a place where I would insert my desired URL mask like " site.bb/x/* " so after I would right click on the element / object (on the site.aa) and via menu hit that button (in context menu), that script would read out the URL behind element / object which matches with a mask (I set up), it would store it into clipboard so all I would need to do is open desktop player and hit paste.

Comment: Tampermonkey has [GM_setClipboard](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#GM_setClipboard) function, but there's no way to open a media player.

Comment: If the URL is an audio field, you could easily create a webapp that downloads the site, searches for the url and inserts it into a HTML5 audio element. It then should play if the codex is supported on web browsers.

Comment: Is it audio or video media? And do you really need it in a specific media player or you just want to show it?

Comment: @jvecsei its video file and for example I would like to open it in daumpotplayer